# In ES6 why can't you refer to sibling methods without using this?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why won't this work, in most other languages I think it'd.

```
class Test {
    a() {
       console.log('hi');
    }
    b() {
      a(); 
    }
}
```

In Java or Ruby this would work. Calling a from b would be completely a Ok.. but in Javascript Class. Why do i need to  put `this.a`, `this.b`, this this this..?

What's the technical reason behind it, what's the benefit, is it going to change as of now - are there plans?

Comment: Not going to change. Benefit is maintaining JavaScript’s simple rules as to what a given name references. Reason is that benefit + classes are fake and prototypes are real (if `Test` didn’t define `a` but a class that inherited from it did, would `a()` still mean `this.a()`?).

Comment: As for "*the technical reason behind it*", best to ask Brendan Eich. But remember that he wrote the basics for what has become ECMAscript in just 10 days and was implementing prototype inheritance, not classes, so the answer might be "*it seemed like a good idea at the time*". ;-)

Comment: @Ryan if child class extends `Test`, then instance of that class would refer to child's `a`, doesnt matter if it was defined in `Test` or not, it'd be over ridden by `child class`.

Comment: parent can't access child's methods anyways

Comment: “parent can't access child's methods anyways” would make no sense in the context of JavaScript. Look at Python’s long-standing class implementation.

Comment: All three languages you listed have different type systems. Why do you expect them to behave the same? This is comparing apples with oranges.

Answer (score 4):

Well, fundamentally, JavaScript doesn't have class-based inheritance.  It has prototype-based inheritance with some syntactic sugar to mimic class-based inheritance.

More generally, there are significant performance problems with trying to determine if `a()` means `this.a()` or if it means another `a()` that exists in a scope that the current function can access.  And that could even change every single time that `b()` is invoked!

Remember, in JavaScript, just because an object has a method `a()` right now doesn't mean it will still have that method `a()` later.  You can delete methods off of objects, and you can add new methods to objects.

Trying to determine which function is the intended target of invocation would basically have exactly the same performance problems that caused `with` to now be deprecated — there are a ton of optimizations that can't happen because you can't determine which method will be invoked until the very moment you'd try to do so.

Comment: Ruby has meta programming where you can add methods on the fly, yet it works fine.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: MRI is insanely slow compared to modern JavaScript engines.

Comment: It's not about "working".  The language could have the feature and it would work, but it would not perform well.  Even today, you could wrap all your methods in `with(this){}` and you'd get the behavior you desire... at a significant performance cost.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: This behaviour – what you’d get with your proposal – is also just… gross. https://ideone.com/D3ZPaN https://ideone.com/4vNtK6

Comment: @Ryan Nice example, however, I don't think in any pattern you would create random kamikaze global functions like that, but I see the merit. Yet note it'd be odd to do so.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with prototypes. It seems it would be trivial to implicitly look up `a` in `b`s `this`, but I'm very happy that that's not how it works.